# Get pixel location of binary image with intensity 255 in python opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I want to get the pixel coordinates of the blue dots in an image.
To get it, I first converted it to gray scale and use threshold function.

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2

    img = cv2.imread("dot.jpg")
    img_g = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret1,th1 = cv2.threshold(img_g,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

What to do next if I want to get the pixel location with intensity 255? Please tell if there is some simpler method to do the same.

Comment: Use inRange() thresholding to get a particular color. The use np.argwhere() to find the location of all the white pixels in the thresholded image.

Comment: If you want to find blue dots, it is not very sensible to convert to greyscale which will make them grey... along with every other pixel. Please show a representative image so we can assist you better. Thank you.

Comment: Convert your RGB image into HSV image and track the blue color. Converting into grayscale will not help that much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is going to work as you would expect.
Usually, in order to get a stable tracking over a shape with a specific color, you do that in RGB/HSV/HSL plane, you could start with **HSV** which is more robust in terms of lighting.

1-Convert to HSV using `cv2.cvtColor()`

2-Use `cv2.inRagne(blue_lower, blue_upper)` to "filter" all un-wanted colors.

Now you have a good-looking binary image with only blue color in it (assuming you have a static background or more filters should be added).

3-Now if you want to detect dots (which is usually more than one pixel) you could try [**cv2.findContours**](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)

4- You can get x,y pixel of contours using many methods(depends on the shape of what you want to detect) like this `cv2.boundingRect()`